# dbt how to create custom table without using CTAS?

Tags: sql, dbt

I want to create an empty table with specific columns and data types, I don't have any reference table from where I can do SELECT * FROM . The following link has an image which I intend to do [Please find the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmJoo.png)

Comment: And the table will be empty?

Comment: yes table would be empty. @dfundako

Comment: Why are you wanting to do that through dbt?

Comment: Dbt is a transformation tool, it can create table with CTAS why couldn't it create with the simple command "create table test". I run into a scenario where I want to create a table with 10 columns and after that put value in only 5 columns of the new table.  @dfundako

Comment: I know what dbt is, but what you're trying to accomplish isn't what dbt is used for. The standard dbt approach is using a cte to query from another source/model and materialize a new view/table. You're trying to do a step to make an empty table, which usually doesn't happen in dbt. You're probably better off doing a seed file and defining the datatypes in your yml files.

Comment: Thank you! I saw seed in the documentation. So, it means we can't create an empty table on the go. But we lay down the foundation of tables by using seeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pre-hook/post-hook](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/pre-hook-post-hook).

In pre-hook/post-hook you can write a create table query (or any other query).

In your use case, I would do something like:

```
{{
   config(
       pre-hook = "create table test (a int)"
   )
}}

select * 
from test
```