# Can we create empty table in dbt (for cold starts)?

Tags: sql, dbt

I have a model that refers to a view that uses the same table that this model creates but getting the previous day.

To be much clearer:

```sql
model_vw.sql

select *
from model
where date='{{prevday}}'
```

Then we have this "main" model that uses this view:

```sql
model.sql

with cte as (
    select *
    from source_table
)
select *
from cte
inner join model_vw prev
on cte.id = prev.id
```

With the way dbt works (as how I understood it), `model.sql` would fail because the table doesn't exist yet. Is there a way to create all tables first without any data before we do `dbt run`?

Comment: Add a filter condition like 1 = 0 to the models then the models will run, there won't be any data. Do this to the models that read data from source because if no data is read from the source then the following models also won't have any data. This will help fulfill your use case of creating the tables / views without any data.

Comment: You're violating some basic DBT rules here. First off, you should be using `ref()` to bring in dependencies on other models. If you were to do that with your example, it would fail because you have a circular dependency. Not sure what your full use case is here, but your approach is going to give you big problems.

Comment: You could use [pre-hook/post-hook](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/pre-hook-post-hook). Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69377677/dbt-how-to-create-custom-table-without-using-ctas).